# Is Honda Shine Rear-Suspension claimable on Warranty\Extended Warranty

Tags: honda, motorcycle, suspension

I own a Honda Shine (125cc) bike which started giving a less cushioning problem on its rear suspension since it was near to its second service (1200 km, 5 months from purchase). Though I told the same to service persons all the time since 2nd service to the latest one (6th service), there was no item regarding that was marked in the job sheets though they assured to look on that. In effect, there was no fix happened on it.

Last service person, guided me to adjust the suspension level by the adjuster as given in the below image. But, I don't feel much of a difference by that as well.

[image]

The questions I have are:

- Is this a common problem in Honda Shine bike or not?
- If so is it fixable by replacing the suspension?
- If replaced is it going to fix it permanently or just temporary?
- Is it something covered under the Warranty\Extended Warranty of the bike (parts covered in warranty are listed in the below image)?

[image]

Comment: Is this a new bike?

Comment: Bought on 21 Dec 2013. Warranty is for 2 years. And extended warranty for another 3 years.

Comment: The reason I brought it up is that you are still under manufacturer's warranty. I'm surprised you are worried about the extended warranty already. And, no, this would not be covered under your extended warranty.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong mention, I meant actually warranty. I mean I can't understand the lists of parts covered as mentioned in the image (from warranty manual) as it is too technical and I am not having much of mechanical know how to understand that.

Comment: All of the parts mentioned above are part of the engine and drivetrain in simple words only your engine and gearbox is covered. And any damage to the gearbox due to broken chain is not covered."YOUR SUSPENSION IS NOT COVERED"

Comment: When you say you are having problem with suspension , can you elaborate? how does it react to small bumps? how does it react to large bumps? how does it react when you are alone? how does it react when you are with a pillion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your suspension compresses fully even in small bumps then try changing the pre-load and tighten your suspension be careful as to not tighten it too much as it will make bike bouncy.

If you are convinced that your suspension is broken(*do check with your mechanic and confirm , you might not know if its really broken since the suspension comes in two parts the coil and damper*) which I don't suspect then read the below pointers.

- The problem with your bike is that it has a duel suspension setup so
  you cannot change just one you need to change both but since your
  bike is relatively new I would suggest changing the bad one first and checking if the ride is good since the other one is also relatively new.If your ride is weird then change both.
- No Not all Honda shines have this problem.
- According to the warranty parts your suspension is not covered but check with the showroom since the bike is new the showroom people **Might** again  **Might** fix it for free(or a minimal charge) since I had an issue with the rear sprocket after 800 kms and they fixed it for free.
- And Yes it will be a permanent solution.